# An image on my employers wordpress site isn't linking properly

Tags: html, image, url, hyperlink, href

Upfront, here is the code:

```
<a href="https://driveweb.com/smarty-universal-automation-2-2/#smarty-dw250">
    <div align=center>
        <img src="https://driveweb.com/wp-content/uploads/dw25x1_Label.png" alt="smarty7 with label NEW smarty7" style="width:403.06px;height:900px;">
    </div>
</a>
```

I'm trying to link each of three picture's in a series on my employers webpage to another section of the webpage by clicking on it but nothing happens when you click on it. It recognizes the link because when you click it it changes the URL in the search bar appropriately and if you right click the image and say open in new tab then it works but it doesn't other wise.

Pointedly, my question is this: What is wrong with my HTML to make it not link when the image is clicked?

Here is a link to the relevant webpage: https://driveweb.com/smarty-universal-automation-2-2/

Each image on this page is supposed to link to the appropriate sub-headed page at the top of the page ("smarty overview", "smarty dw250", "smarty dw240", and "smarty dw210").

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I should've said this initially but I wanted to lend further clarification. I've decided to focus on the 1st in a series of three photos but they're all having the same problem.

Comment: It worked fine for me, once I clicked the image it redirected to the link properly.

Comment: That's great news @MatthewRBevins If you don't mind could you tell me what browser and/or OS you're using? We've tried it on multiple browsers on separate computers and it seemed to not be working pretty universally. If you have any idea why this might be happening I'd love to hear.